# Kotlin/Native - does this mean Kotlin & Kotlin Native or Kotlin Native

Tags: kotlin, native

Kotlin documentation is full of mentioning "Kotlin/Native"

Example:

> There are many more platform libraries available for host and cross-compilation targets. **Kotlin/Native** distribution provides access to OpenGL, zlib and other popular native libraries on applicable platforms. - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-platform-libs.html#popular-native-libraries

Does "Kotlin/Native" mean:

- Kotlin Native

or does it mean

- Kotlin & Kotlin Native

Answer (score 1):

*Kotlin/Native* is the name used just for the Native targets of Kotlin.

In general, something is said to support Kotlin Multiplatform if it targets Kotlin/JVM (+Android), Kotlin/JS, and Kotlin/Native – or a subset of those – while *Kotlin/Native* means specifically the targets that assume compiling Kotlin to the platform's native binaries.